# How to use aliases in Vagrant

Tags: bash, shell, vagrant, alias

I'm trying to create aliases that I can use in Vagrant any time I run the VM.  I've found several sources on the web about it, but can't get it working.  I tried making a .bash_profile in my synced folder, but that didn't work.  I noticed if I run the command alias name="command" this will work, but only for the current session.  Anyone know how to do this?  I'm using macOS.  Thanks for your help!

Here is my Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

unless Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-vbguest")
    warn "\nWARNING: The vagrant-vbguest plugin should be installed or your shared folders might not mount properly!"
    warn "You can do this by running the command 'vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest'.\n\n"
end

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "pype_vm"
  config.vm.box_url = "https://.../pype_vm.json"

  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: ""
  config.vm.boot_timeout = 600
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    # This forces VirtualBox to use the host's DNS resolver instead of
    # VirtualBox's
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "", "on"]

    # This enables the PAE/NX option, which resolved at least one user's
    # issues with the VM hanging on boot
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--pae", "on"]

    # The RHEL VM was created with 2GB of memory to facilitate provisioning,
    # but this is causing issues with certain workstations.  This reduces
    # the amount of memory allocated to the VM but should not impact development
    # performance.  The number is in MB and can be increased if desired.
    v.memory = 1024
  end
  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. 
  config.vm.synced_folder File.dirname(__FILE__), "/pype"
end
```

Comment: Aliases are an interactive facility -- they're not intended for use with noninteractive shells. What are the details of your use case?

Comment: (if you're running an interactive shell inside the container, you'll need to ensure that your `.bash_profile` is *inside the container*).

Comment: ...btw, I'd strongly suggest using an exported function instead; that way it carries through to shells run as subprocesses. With a bit of care, you can even put the definition into your Vagrantfile as an environment variable.

Comment: (btw, `command` is actually the name of a shell builtin, so it's generally a good idea to use a different placeholder)

Comment: ...but seriously, though: We need more information to be able to provide an authoritative answer to this question -- *at minimum*, which flags the shell inside the container is being started with. (With `-l`, it will consider itself a login shell; with `-i` it will consider itself interactive; both of these influence which dotfiles are honored on startup). A minimal Dockerfile and command line for invoking the container would be the ideal place to start.

Comment: all I do to get into the virtual environment is run vagrant up, vagrant ssh, which gives me a shell on the VM that has a synched folder on my local machine

Comment: I don't have a Dockerfile.  I tried to give details as best as I can but I (obviously) don't understand all the details of what's going on here.

Comment: Sorry -- I should have been asking for a Vagrantfile, vs a Dockerfile.

Comment: What's the home directory of the user you're logging in as inside the guest? (You're sync'ing the current directory to `/pype` -- but is that actually the relevant `$HOME`?)

Comment: Ah! No, the $HOME is /home/vagrant ... and I found that there is a /home/vagrant/.bash_aliases file where I can save aliases.  That's was what I needed, thank you Charles!

Comment: Good deal. I've added an answer, such that by accepting it you can mark the problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The details depend on the specific of the guest being run, but some notes:

- Assuming the default user account is active for `vagrant ssh`, ensure that any dotfiles you wish to override are copied to `/home/vagrant`.
- If overriding `.bashrc`, ensure that the remote shell is started with the interactive flag (if this is true, `echo $-` will include `i`).
- If overriding `.bash_profile`, ensure that the remote shell is started as a login shell (if this is true, `echo $-` will include `l`).

Comment: How do you put the `.bash_profile` into `home/vagrant`?